# Volatile table can not be create in python importing pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, teradata, pyodbc

The code is below, by the way the database I use is teradata ,and in a windows 7 operative system and python version 2.7.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=thisIsAbsolutelyCorrect;UID=cannottellyou;PWD=iamsosorry')
cursor1 = cnxn.cursor()
cursor1=cursor1.execute(
##################        OR put your SQL dirctly between here        ################
'''

create volatile table table1
(
field1  integer
,field2 integer
)on commit preserve rows;
--insert into table1
--values(12,13);
--select   * from table1;






''')  
#########################        and here         ########################
cnxn.commit()
for row in cursor1:
    print row
raw_input()
```

But I get the error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\issuser\Desktop\py\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    for row in cursor1:
ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: What are you trying to print? The insert and select statements are commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursor object will have no rows to iterate through. What I think you want is to iterate through the results of an execute.

```
rows = curs.execute(""" sql code """).fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row
```

here is a template to upload to a volatile table in teradata from python2.7 using pyodbc:

---

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('your_connection_string')
curs = cnxn.cursor()
curs.execute("""
    CREATE VOLATILE TABLE TABLE_NAME
        (
        c_0 dec(10,0),
        ...
        c_n dec(10,0)
        ) PRIMARY INDEX (c0)
        ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
        END TRANSACTION;
        """)

curs.execute("""
    INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (c_0,...,c_n) VALUES (%s);
    """%value_string)
```

Depending on your settings in Teradata you must explicitly END TRANSACTION.
You can add your loop around the INSERT to upload information line by line.

Comment: you are so right !
what i misunderstanded actually is the difference between
    1.  curs.execute()
and 2.  something=curs.execute()
;when you create a volatile table ,it is actually nothing return.so there will be no need to give to a variable ,in order to print it out. we can do a lot of 1. before the need of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=thisIsAbsolutelyCorrect;UID=cannottellyou;PWD=iamsosorry')
cursor1 = cnxn.cursor()
RowCount=cursor1.execute(
'''
create volatile table table1
(
field1  integer
,field2 integer
)on commit preserve rows;
''').rowcount   

RowCount=cursor1.execute('''insert into table1 values(12,13);''').rowcount

cnxn.commit()

for row in cursor1:
    print row
raw_input()
```

I believe the issue is that the `EXECUTE()` method as you have written is expecting a cursor to be returned. DDL and DML statements like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` to not return result sets. You may have more success in using the `ROWCOUNT` variable with the `EXECUTE()` method to process the volatile table creation and its population.

You may also have to issue a commit between the creation of the volatile table and populating the table.